# How to import installed packages from python venv

Tags: python, pandas, python-venv

I am new to python, I have installed pandas in venv but when I import in my script , I see this error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "predict.py", line 1, in 
> import pandas as pd
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'

Here is my script

```
import pandas as pd

def get_data():
    pd.read_csv('ames-housing-dataset.zip' )
    
get_data()
```

[project directory setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cgZoc.png)

Here I want to understand how do I import pandas library correctly?

Comment: Did you activate the env?

Comment: it seems wherever you installed `pandas` is not the same version of python running the script. how do you invoke the script?

Comment: you have to run python inside the virtual env. how do you created your venv (conda, python-venv,..) ? You have to activate this venv, and then run your python in there (console, spyder, or the soft that you're ussing)

Comment: Hi @chenzhongpu, I believe I did activate the env because I ran this cmd               
apt install python3.8-venv;python3 -m venv env;env/bin/pip install pandas scikit-learn pytest

Comment: Hi @gold_cy, I run the script using python3 filename.py

Comment: Hi @UlisesBussi, I cerated python-venv, also activated the env by running python3 -m venv env. Can you check image in my question and tell where do I place my script file in the directory tree?

Comment: ` python3 -m venv env` is to create a venv, not to **activate**.

Comment: Thanks @chenzhongpu, can you tell where in the tree do I need to place my script?

Comment: You can put the script at any place as long as you activate this env. Depending on your OS, bash: `source <venv>/bin/activate`; Windows cmd: `<venv>\Scripts\activate.bat`; Windows powershell: `<venv>\Scripts\Activate.ps1`. <venv> must be replaced by the path of the directory containing the virtual environment.